# Add line opcache.preload=/app/tools/preload.php in opcache.ini not working in docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, composer-php, preload, php-7.4

I'm trying to connect a preload that was added in php7.4, but I'm facing this problem:

```
Step 11/11 : RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/bin --filename=composer --quiet     && rm -rf /root/.composer/cache
 ---> Running in 0ce2e24e155c
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Fatal error:  Failed opening required '/app/tools/preload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Failed opening required '/app/tools/preload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in Unknown on line 0
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 16366)
ERROR: Service 'project-php-cli' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/bin --filename=composer --quiet     && rm -rf /root/.composer/cache' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

For some reason the script does not see the file in the path I specified.

```
opcache.preload=/app/tools/preload.php
opcache.preload_user=www-data
```

Perhaps I did not understand the fact that my folder is not in the image yet, therefore the script file is not visible [image]
If so then how do i add my files to the preload

Comment: did you found a solution to this?

Comment: Did not find, postponed for the future.

Comment: I solve the issue by not writing the opcache.preload stuff into the php.ini directly, but to use a command in the dockerfile to patch the php.ini after everything was set up correctly: `RUN echo "opcache.preload=/var/www/preload.php" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-opcache.ini`

Comment: If this solved the problem, please leave an answer, I will mark and will definitely try, thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solve the issue by not writing the opcache.preload stuff into the php.ini directly, but to use a command in the Dockerfile to patch the php.ini after the container installed php and additional extensions correctly:

```
RUN echo "opcache.preload=/var/www/preload.php" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-opcache.ini
```